# Div will not display inline

Tags: html, css

I have a container with two basic elements. A header and the body. In the header div I want a 50px by 50px image and a user name next to it, but I can't seem to get the username to display inline. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/14/

Answer (score 1):

Add a float: left to both elements. Like:

```
#story-teller-head-contain img{
  float: left;
  /* your other styling */
}

#story-teller-head-contain h1 {
  float: left;
  /* your other styling */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a float left to the image and the div containing the name, I have updated your jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/15/

Comment: You should also remove the superfluous `display: inline`s.

Answer (score 0):

can you use `inline-block` instead `inline` for the `div` with username or `float` bot `img` and `div.

Demo with `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/16/

Demo with `float`: http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/17/

Answer (score 0):

Inline display can be a bit of a pain. The cross browser way to do it is like this..

```
/* Older version of FF */
display: -moz-inline-stack;

/* newer versions of FF and Webkit */
display: inline-block;

/* trigger the correct behaviour in IE */
zoom:1;

/* IE */
*display: inline;
```

You need to declare the style sin that order.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the following structure (I've added an image url so we can see that element):

```
<div id="story-teller-head-contain">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
    <div id="client-name">
        <h1> Matt Morris </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `div` elements and `h1` are all block-level elements by default. However, all you need to do is `float: left` the `img` and `#client-name` elements, and they will flow left to their width (which you declare), without forcing the next element to flow beneath.

```
#story-teller-head-contain img {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#client-name {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

#story-teller-head-contain h1 {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3B5998;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/21/

So you're not really looking for `display: inline`, which will attempt to display the element's as "inline text" is displayed (such as this paragraph text); what you want is for the `img` and `#client-name` elements to not "force `clear` after". Your `display: inline` is what is allowing the `h1`, which is a block-level element, to disrupt your display, since it is overriding the `display: inline` of the parent element.

In fact, if you inspect with Firebug or Chrome Console, you'll see the above computes as `float: left` and `display: block`, even though `display: block` has not been explicitly declared.

See:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
- http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is saying make the image and persons name `float: left;`
http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/20/

By the way, i really like the set up you did here. So i messed with your source some:
http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/22/

Answer (score 0):

```
I feel its better to use -

img{
   float:left;
}
#client-name{
   display: table-cell;
   zoom:1;/*For IE only*/ 
}
```

You don't have to specify widths like in float method. It will automatically accommodate text with varying length.

I have updated your code - http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/27/

But I think your structure & css could be much more simpler. Since I don't know about the purpose, left it untouched.